# SVN: How to create another branch of already checkout branch

Tags: svn

I have taken checkout of a project (for ex Project1) in svn. Now i have made alot of changes in Project1,now i do not want to change Project1 by committing my changes. I want another branch in SVN by exporting project including my changes

Answer (score 7):

In svn a branch is just a copy operation so just use

```
svn copy ORIG_URL DEST_URL -m "Message about this new branch"
```

where `ORIG_URL` and `DEST_URL` are remote urls.

In svn the copy is done in the server and it will create a new revision.

If your context allows, switch to `git` it is much more flexible handling branches.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you can create a new branch by using

```
svn copy existing_branch_url new_branch_url
```

What I'd like to add is that you can then just point your working copy to this new branch with

```
svn switch new_branch_url
```

and then

```
svn commit
```

Comment: `svn commit` is not necessary, `copy` creates a revision as I stated in the other answer.

Comment: SVN copy from existing repository branch is unaware of a working copy. It does not commit your local changes.

Answer (score -2):

As Jonas has already mentioned, You need to copy your existing branch in SVN and create a new one.

```
svn copy old_url new_url -m "Your commit message"
```

Checkout the code from this branch. Merge all your local changes to this newly checked out branch and commit.